# Regular Expression that return matches specific strings in bracket and return its next and preceding string in brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to find the string in brackets that matches some specific string and all values in the string.
Right not I am getting values from a position where the string matches.

```
text = 'This is an sample string which have some information in brackets (info; matchingString, someotherString).'

regex= r"\(*?matchingString.*?\)"
matches = re.findall(regex, text)
```

From this I am getting result
matchingString, someotherString)
what I want is to get the string before the matching string as well.
The result should be like this:
(info; matchingString, someotherString)
This regex works if the matching string is in the first string in brackets.

Comment: Use `r"\([^()]*?matchingString[^)]*\)"`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v582wx/1).

Comment: There should be a `.` in `\(.*?` or else you match optional parenthesis giving you the partial match.

Comment: No, that above-mentioned stack overflow link question does not answer the question.
But I take help from there and was able to create a regex which is mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\([^()]*?matchingString[^)]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v582wx/1/). Due to the `[^()]*?`, the match will never overflow  across other `(...)` substrings.

*Regex details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*?` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` as few as possible
- `matchingString` - a hardcoded string
- `[^)]*` - zero or more chars other than `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WpkZsl):

```py
import re
text = 'This is an sample string which have some information in brackets (info; matchingString, someotherString).'
regex= r"\([^()]*?matchingString[^)]*\)"
print( re.findall(regex, text) )
# => ['(info; matchingString, someotherString)']
```

Comment: yes, thanks this answers the question. Just one problem arises when I use 
r"\([^()]*?matchingString[^)]*\)" , 
this regex breaks if there is a URL at the end of brackets for example:
the regex result is match='(version 2.26B, MTI Health Services, http://www.m> 
but it should be matched like this:
 (version 2.26B, MTI Health Services, http://www.mtifwb.com)
When matching string is MTI Health Services.

Comment: @AbdulMuqeet No idea what you mean. If you need follow up help, please share a regex101.com fiddle.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. Actually I was using about a new regex in which I want to find the one exact string followed by et.al then some digit.
For achieving this I created a regex that works for some strings but I am not sure if it works for every string.
Can you please correct this? this would be really helpful for me thanks.
https://regex101.com/r/hspAND/1

Comment: @AbdulMuqeet Sorry, that is not clear to me, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hspAND/2).